# Apply an element-wise function on a pandas dataframe with index and column values as inputs

Tags: pandas

I often have this need, and I can't seem to find the way to do it efficiently.

Let's say I have a pandas DataFrame object and I want the value of each element `(i,j)` to be equal to `f(index[i], columns[j])`.

Using `applymap`, value of index and column for each element is lost.

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on what you are trying to do specifically.

***clever hack***
using `pd.Panel.apply`
it works because it will iterate over each series along the major and minor axes.  It's name will be the tuple we need.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(5), columns=range(5))

def f1(x):
    n = x.name
    return n[0] + n[1] ** 2

pd.Panel(dict(A=df)).apply(f1, 0)

   0  1  2   3   4
0  0  1  4   9  16
1  1  2  5  10  17
2  2  3  6  11  18
3  3  4  7  12  19
4  4  5  8  13  20
```

***example 1***
Here is one such use case and one possible solution for that use case

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(5), columns=range(5))

f = lambda x: x[0] + x[1]

s = df.stack(dropna=False)
s.loc[:] = s.index.map(f)
s.unstack()

   0  1  2  3  4
0  0  1  2  3  4
1  1  2  3  4  5
2  2  3  4  5  6
3  3  4  5  6  7
4  4  5  6  7  8
```

or this will do the same thing

```
df.stack(dropna=False).to_frame().apply(lambda x: f(x.name), 1).unstack()
```

***example 2***

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=list('abcd'), columns=list('xyz'))

v = df.values
c = df.columns.values
i = df.index.values

pd.DataFrame(
    (np.tile(i, len(c)) + c.repeat(len(i))).reshape(v.shape),
    i, c
)

    x   y   z
a  ax  bx  cx
b  dx  ay  by
c  cy  dy  az
d  bz  cz  dz
```

Comment: That works and that's exactly my need. I just don't find it super intuitive and direct. It's funny that there isn't an "easy" way to do this

Comment: pd.Panel is deprecated since pandas 0.20.0